# How to create a dataframe from a built in vector

Tags: r

I tried to create a dataframe from the built in data (its a vector) called percip. Here is the code below:

```
data("precip")
str(precip)
 Named num [1:70] 67 54.7 7 48.5 14 17.2 20.7 13 43.4 40.2 ...
attr(*, "names")= chr [1:70] "Mobile" "Juneau" "Phoenix" "Little Rock" ...
head(precip)
 Mobile      Juneau     Phoenix Little Rock Los Angeles  Sacramento 
   67.0        54.7         7.0        48.5        14.0        17.2
```

How do I create a dataframe where I have the name of the city in one column and the numbers in another column?

Comment: See `help(data.frame)`.  This is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame("City" = names(precip), precip)
```

Comment: for some reason my upvote doesn't count, but thanks dude for your help, learning r is tough but rewarding